# How to get the number of SQL queries ran through Athena?

Tags: sql, amazon-web-services, amazon-athena

How to get the number of SQL queries ran through Athena?

Comment: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/athena/latest/APIReference/API_ListQueryExecutions.html